# Filter API JSON response with Python 3.8

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.8

doing a request on an API with python have the next json answer:

```
.
.
.
      },

    "locationLatitude": "string",
    "locationLongitude": "string",
    "lastSyncTimeStamp": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.565Z",
    "isPowerTrainComponent": true,
    "sensorTypeID": 0,
    "sensorIdentifier": "string",
    "assetGroupID": 0,
    "assetResponsibleID": 0,
    "assetResponsibleName": "string",
    "assetID": 0,
    "assetName": "string",
    "serialNumber": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "configurationProfileID": 0,
    "configurationProfileName": "string",
    "isMonitored": true 
.
.
.
```

I want to filter the loop response to only obtain the "assetname" and "lastSyncTimeStamp" of each loop. and i have the following code but it doesnt work... Thanks for the help!

```
.
.
.
    # Iterate the plant list and print all assets therein
    for plant in plants:

        # Get list of assets
        response = client.get_asset_list(organization_id=client.organization_id)
        if len(response) == 0:
            print('No assets in this plant')
        else:
            for asset in response:
                print(asset,"assetName","lastSyncTimeStamp")

    return True
.
.
.
```

Comment: What does `get_asset_list()` return? What is `client` exactly? The JSON fragment you shared is incomplete and invalid, without knowing how it's structured, it's impossible to say what your code should be. You say it doesn't work, but what actually happens? Do you get an error message, or does it always print `'no assets in this plant'`?

Comment: What type of data is in `response`? Is it a string holding the JSON data, or is it JSON already loaded into a Python data structure (dict, list...)?

Comment: The lowercase `true` in your sample suggests that it's just a string that you first need to load using `json.loads(response)`.

Comment: The code works but i dont know how to filter the responses. I posted the full code

Answer (score 0):

The response is a list of dicts but

As your response contains ***true*** which is unrecognized by Python interpreter so you can use `json.loads` to convert that to ***True***

```
import json

response =  json.loads('''[
  {
    "uniqueID": "string",
    "assetGroupName": "string",
    "isGroup": true,
    "assetProperties": [
      {
        "assetPropertyValue": {},
        "assetPropertyDataType": "string",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "assetPropertyAvailableValueID": 0,
        "assetPropertyName": "string",
        "assetPropertyPrecision": 0,
        "measurementUnitGroup": {
          "measurementUnitGroupID": 0,
          "measurementUnitGroupName": "string",
          "measurementUnitDefault": "string"
        },
        "assetPropertySequenceNr": 0,
        "assetPropertyType": "string"
      }
    ],
    "labels": [
      {
        "labelID": 0,
        "labelAssignedOn": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
        "labelValue": "string"
      }
    ],
    "assetPictures": [
      {
        "picturePath": [
          {
            "size": 1,
            "path": "string"
          }
        ],
        "timestamp": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
        "uniqueID": "string",
        "pictureType": 0
      }
    ],
    "measurements": [
      {
        "measurementTypeID": 0,
        "measurementTypeCode": "string",
        "measurementTypeName": "string",
        "timeStamp": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
        "measurementValue": {},
        "measurementCalibration": 0,
        "isCalibrationEnabled": true,
        "healthStatus": {
          "healthCode": 0,
          "healthColor": "string"
        },
        "measurementTypeUnitGroupID": 0,
        "measurementTypeUnitGroupName": "string",
        "isEditable": true,
        "isHealthParameter": true,
        "isVisible": true,
        "isCumulative": true,
        "uniqueID": "string",
        "measurementTypePrecision": 0,
        "enableDataValidation": true,
        "qualityFlag": 0,
        "measurementTypeDescription": "string",
        "measurementTypeSequenceNo": 0
      }
    ],
    "firmwareUpdate": {
      "updateAvailable": true,
      "updateFirmwareID": 0,
      "updateFirmwareVersion": "string"
    },
    "sensor": {
      "sensorIdentifier": "string",
      "hardware": {
        "hardwareRevisionID": 0,
        "hardwareRevisionName": "string"
      },
      "firmwareVersion": "string",
      "commissioningDate": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
      "features": [
        {
          "featureKey": "string",
          "featureValue": {},
          "timeStamp": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
          "isVisible": true,
          "featureName": "string",
          "featureKeySequenceNo": 0
        }
      ],
      "properties": [
        {
          "propertyValue": {},
          "propertyKey": "string",
          "propertyName": "string",
          "propertyKeySequenceNo": 0,
          "propertyDataType": "string",
          "propertyIsVisible": true
        }
      ],
      "subscription": {
        "startDate": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
        "endDate": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.564Z",
        "hasAvailableSubscriptions": true,
        "isBasicSubscription": true,
        "isTrialSubscription": true,
        "subscriptionLevel": {
          "name": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "id": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": [
      {
        "conditionIndexKey": "string",
        "conditionIndexName": "string",
        "conditionIndexStatus": {
          "status": 0,
          "statusCode": "string",
          "statusCodeMessage": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "healthStatus": {
      "healthCode": 0,
      "healthColor": "string"
    },
    "assetType": {
      "assetTypeID": 0,
      "assetTypeName": "string",
      "assetTypeDescription": "string"
    },
    "plantID": 0,
    "plantName": "string",
    "siteIdentifier": "string",
    "isFavourite": true,
    "createdOn": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.565Z",
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.565Z",
    "organization": {
      "organizationID": 0,
      "isPrivateOrgarnization": true,
      "organizationName": "string"
    },
    "locationLatitude": "string",
    "locationLongitude": "string",
    "lastSyncTimeStamp": "2020-06-11T08:01:01.565Z",
    "isPowerTrainComponent": true,
    "sensorTypeID": 0,
    "sensorIdentifier": "string",
    "assetGroupID": 0,
    "assetResponsibleID": 0,
    "assetResponsibleName": "string",
    "assetID": 0,
    "assetName": "string",
    "serialNumber": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "configurationProfileID": 0,
    "configurationProfileName": "string",
    "isMonitored": true
  }
]''')
```

just use the get method on response dict to get the desired values.

```
for each_dict in response:
  print(each_dict.get("assetName"), each_dict.get("lastSyncTimeStamp"))
```